# How can I get the ppid from a oom killed process?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory, pid

I’m using docker, there are more than ten containers running in my machine. I found some oom log in /var/log/message, but I can't figure out those killed process belong which container. 
/var/log/message log as below：

> kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 165480 (java) score 987 or
>   sacrifice child

Comment: First of all if your process is already dead it would be very difficult to find the parent... what you can do is when your processes are running to dump their pid and ppid in some files with timestamp and do that on a regular basis (every minute, 2 minutes, ...) then whenever one of your process dies you can directly find the parent

Comment: Seems only this way. Thank you~